# Override mtdparts configured in kernel device tree

Tags: debian, device-tree, flash

I've installed Debian Buster on a "ReadyNAS 102" via u-boot / serial console. I was following [this tutorial](https://www.hillenius.com/post/installing_debian_jessie_on_a_netgear_readynas_102/). But, replaced used different links to download current the Debian installer and Device Tree Blob:

- http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/main/installer-armhf/current/images/device-tree/armada-370-netgear-rn102.dtb
- http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/main/installer-armhf/current/images/netboot/initrd.gz
- http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/main/installer-armhf/current/images/netboot/vmlinuz

Installation worked fine, except for the installation of grub (which is known to fail according to the tutorial). Instead you've to manually install/configure the `flash-kernel` package.

I also had to manually call "mtdpart" to create the `uImage` and `minirootfs` partitions to finally be able to successfully run "update-initramfs":

```
# mtdpart add /dev/mtd0 uImage 0x200000 0x600000
# mtdpart add /dev/mtd0 minirootfs 0x800000 0x1000000
# update-initramfs -u
```

So far so good. I got the kernel booting, but after booting I've some preconfigured "mtd partitions", which seem to originate from the kernel device tree:

```
~# cat /proc/mtd
dev:    size   erasesize  name
mtd0: 00180000 00020000 "u-boot"
mtd1: 00020000 00020000 "u-boot-env"
mtd2: 00600000 00020000 "uImage"
mtd3: 00400000 00020000 "minirootfs"
mtd4: 07400000 00020000 "ubifs"
```

The problem with this is: "minirootfs" is too small (only 4 MB) for the generated initramfs:

```
 # update-initramfs -u -k 4.19.0-6-armmp
 update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-6-armmp
 Using DTB: armada-370-netgear-rn102.dtb
 Installing /usr/lib/linux-image-4.19.0-6-armmp/armada-370-netgear-rn102.dtb into /boot/dtbs/4.19.0-6-armmp/./armada-370-netgear-rn102.dtb
 Taking backup of armada-370-netgear-rn102.dtb.
 Installing new armada-370-netgear-rn102.dtb.
 Installing /usr/lib/linux-image-4.19.0-6-armmp/armada-370-netgear-rn102.dtb into /boot/dtbs/4.19.0-6-armmp/./armada-370-netgear-rn102.dtb
 Taking backup of armada-370-netgear-rn102.dtb.
 Installing new armada-370-netgear-rn102.dtb.
 flash-kernel: installing version 4.19.0-6-armmp

 The initial ramdisk is too large. This is often due to the unnecessary inclusion
 of all kernel modules in the image. To fix this set MODULES=dep in one or both
 /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/driver-policy (if it exists) and
 /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf and then run 'update-initramfs -u -k 4.19.0-6-armmp'

 Not enough space for initrd in MTD 'minirootfs' (need 4971360 but is actually 4194304).
 run-parts: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//flash-kernel exited with return code 1
```

The new /dev/mtd0 to /dev/mtd4 devices can not be removed, edited or recreated by mtdpart. I also tried to set the `mtdparts` kernel parameter (which needs to be 'cmdlinepart.mtdparts' due to a bug in buster; I've tried 'mtdparts=' too):

```
# cat /proc/cmdline
console=ttyS0,115200 cmdlinepart.mtdparts=armada-nand:0x180000@0(u-boot),0x20000@0x180000(u-boot-env),(uImage),0x1000000@0x800000(minirootfs),-(ubi)
```

The mtd partitions seem to be defined in the *.dtb file that comes with the kernel:

The following message appears in "dmesg" speaking about "5 fixed-partions".

```
   [   18.310935] 5 fixed-partitions partitions found on MTD device pxa3xx_nand-0
   [   18.318030] Creating 5 MTD partitions on "pxa3xx_nand-0":
   root@ReadyNAS102:~# dmesg | grep 'MTD' -A 3
   [   18.310935] 5 fixed-partitions partitions found on MTD device pxa3xx_nand-0
   [   18.318030] Creating 5 MTD partitions on "pxa3xx_nand-0":
   (...some other lines...)
   [   18.443214] 0x000000000000-0x000000180000 : "u-boot"
   [   18.497255] 0x000000180000-0x0000001a0000 : "u-boot-env"
   [   18.543756] 0x000000200000-0x000000800000 : "uImage"
   [   18.601234] 0x000000800000-0x000000c00000 : "minirootfs"
   [   18.661169] 0x000000c00000-0x000008000000 : "ubifs"
```

I tried to edit the *.dtb file that comes with the kernel (/boot/dtbs/4.19.0-6-armmp/armada-370-netgear-rn102.dts) by using the dtc tool:

```
# dtc -I dtb -O dts armada-370-netgear-rn102.dtb > armada-370-netgear-rn102.dts
# editing the *.dts file
# dtc -I dts -O dtb armada-370-netgear-rn102.dts > armada-370-netgear-rn102.dtb
```

I changed the *.dts file as following:

```
 nand-controller@d0000 {
       compatible = "marvell,armada370-nand-controller";
       reg = < 0xd0000 0x54 >;
       #address-cells = < 0x01 >;
       #size-cells = < 0x00 >;
       interrupts = < 0x71 >;
       clocks = < 0x0d 0x00 >;
       status = "okay";

       nand@0 {
               reg = < 0x00 >;
               label = "pxa3xx_nand-0";
               nand-rb = < 0x00 >;
               marvell,nand-keep-config;
               nand-on-flash-bbt;
               nand-ecc-strength = < 0x04 >;
               nand-ecc-step-size = < 0x200 >;

               partitions {
                       compatible = "fixed-partitions";
                       #address-cells = < 0x01 >;
                       #size-cells = < 0x01 >;

                       partition@0 {
                               label = "u-boot";
                               reg = < 0x00 0x180000 >;
                               read-only;
                       };

                       partition@180000 {
                               label = "u-boot-env";
                               reg = < 0x180000 0x20000 >;
                               read-only;
                       };

                       partition@200000 {
                               label = "uImage";
                               reg = < 0x200000 0x600000 >;
                       };

                       partition@800000 {
                               label = "minirootfs";
                               reg = < 0x800000 0x1000000 >;
                       };

                       partition@c00000 {
                               label = "ubifs";
                               reg = < 0xc00000 0x7400000 >;
                       };
               };
       };
};
```

Especially, I changed "reg = < 0x800000 0x400000 >;" to "reg = < 0x800000 0x1000000 >;" for `partition@800000`:

```
                       partition@800000 {
                               label = "minirootfs";
                               reg = < 0x800000 0x1000000 >;
                       };
```

There's enough space before the "ubifs" partition and I don't use it anyways. But, after a reboot the kernel still tells me about the old settings. How can I fix that?

I could probably manually install "vmlinuz + *.dtb" to the NAND via uboot. But, that would be gone as soon as the next kernel update is installed.

I would prefer the kernel to interpret the "mtdparts" command line parameter.

Any ideas?

### EDIT #1:

I now (ab)use the partition "ubifs" instead of "minirootfs" for the initramfs. This works, but I would like to know if there is a more clean solution. Of course, I also had to change my "bootcmd" at u-boot to load/use data from this partition instead:

```
setenv bootcmd 'nand read 0x2000000 0x200000 0x600000; nand read 0x3000000 0xc00000 0x800000; bootm 0x2000000 0x3000000'
saveenv
reset
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough to just edit the dtb just like you already tried.

```
    partition@800000 {
      label = "minirootfs";
      reg = <0x0800000 0x800000>;    /* 8MB */
    };

    /* Last MB is for the BBT, i.e. not writable */
    partition@1000000 {
      label = "ubifs";
      reg = <0x01000000 0x7000000>; /* 112MB */
    };
```

I suspect you simply forgot to append the dtb to the kernel.

mtdinfo then reports:

```
    mtd3
    Name:                           minirootfs
    Type:                           nand
    Eraseblock size:                131072 bytes, 128.0 KiB
    Amount of eraseblocks:          64 (8388608 bytes, 8.0 MiB)
    Minimum input/output unit size: 2048 bytes
    Sub-page size:                  2048 bytes
    OOB size:                       64 bytes
    Character device major/minor:   90:6
    Bad blocks are allowed:         true
    Device is writable:             true
```

This is using debian 4.19.0-10 kernel